# Structural types cannot contain implicit members?

Tags: scala

Isn't possible to have structural types with implicit members like this?

```
type Foo = { implicit val fooMsg: String }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a good one.

Refinements take only declarations and type defs --

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/03-types.html#compound-types

and modifiers qualify decls and defs in template statements.

Refinements can override (refine) obviously, but `override` is not allowed either.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you actually define it in a tricky way - it won't see the difference:

```
scala> val a = new { implicit val fooMsg: String = "a" }
a: AnyRef{implicit val fooMsg: String} = $anon$1@7b7b04e9

scala> var b = a
b: AnyRef{implicit val fooMsg: String} = $anon$1@7b7b04e9

scala> b = new { implicit val fooMsg: String = "v" }
b: AnyRef{implicit val fooMsg: String} = $anon$1@7c8adf94

scala> b = new { val fooMsg: String = "v" }
b: AnyRef{implicit val fooMsg: String} = $anon$1@30cff762

scala> b = new { val fooMsgg: String = "v" }
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
 found   : AnyRef{val fooMsgg: String; val fooMsgg: String}
 required: AnyRef{implicit val fooMsg: String}
       b = new { val fooMsgg: String = "v" }
           ^
```

Seems like a bug for me: [SI-9085](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9085).

Comment: There you are at: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4218, i.e., for your anon class, what is inferred for the type.

Comment: ok it's hard to distinguish; but as it didn't actually infer implicit, so at least shouldn't print it in type's `toString`, and then will be fine.

Comment: You can `import a._ ; implicitly[String]`, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Yeah, I just got that you were thinking: implicit doesn't change conformance. But that's OK. The type of B is just what is "leaked" by inference.

Comment: I know, but this `AnyRef{implicit val fooMsg: String}` seems to be very confusing for the user especially as it can't even be parsed

Comment: The fact that such expression can't be parsed was exactly the motivation of my question.

Comment: OK, I see. Someone should write the list of things (types) that exist but can't be written explicitly.

Comment: how about the things that exists, can be written explicitly `AnyRef{...}`, but not always the way there are represented. Because It's a little different from `(String)(String)String` for instance. Shouldn't the language be [POLA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)-consistent at least when it's possible?